# Diagonalization of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I saw in the spectral theorem that any real symmetric matrix $A$ is diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices; i.e., given a real symmetric matrix $A$, $Q^{T} AQ$ is diagonal for some orthogonal matrix $Q$.

I was wondering if we could prove that any real symmetric matrix $A$ is diagonalizable only by using tools and properties of diagonalization (i.e. $P_{car}(X)=\det(A-X\cdot In)$, $A^T=A$, etc...). We do not care about the fact that proving that it is diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices, we just want to show that it is diagonalizable.

I started by thinking about the fact that any real symmetric matrix $A$ has a real eigenvalue (by showing that the characteristic polynomial has a root (complex or real) and this eigenvalue must be real with a small computation proof). But what about multiplicity stuff ? I think I can answer my own question just by saying that if $x_0$ is an eigenvalue then the characteristic polynomial $P(X)$ can be written as $P(X)=(X-x_0)Q(X)$. Then Q(X) has also a complex root that also must be real. But we are only working on the multiplicity of the roots here and nothing tells us that the sum of the geometric multiplicity (= dimension of an eigenvector space associated $x_0$ of another root) is equal to $\dim(A)$ $\iff A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: You can probably write a proof where you "hide" the orthogonal side, but the key point in the spectral theorem is that when you have an eigenvector, then you can find a complement hyperplane which is stable. And usually, this relies on the fact that you can take the *orthogonal hyperplane*, which is stable because $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: The difficult part in the spectral theorem, is to show that the spectrum is non-empty. Indeed, because $A$ is symmetric, the orthogonal complement of a stable space is also stable. So once we have a root, we're done by recursion.

But bear in mind that the spectrum theorem is false for *complex* matrices. So whatever your line of argument is, it must use, crucially, the fact that $A$ is real valued.

Comment: Actually, real symmetric matrices are diagonalisable not because they are *symmetric*, but because they are *self-adjoint*. It just happens that all *real* symmetric matrices are self-adjoint. Symmetric matrices over other fields are not necessarily diagonalisable. E.g. *every* complex square matrix is similar to some complex symmetric matrix, but clearly not every complex square matrix is diagonalisable.